# How do I route VST audio through effects/amp simulator in Cubase?

Tags: guitar-effects, daw, audio, vst, cubase

I have Shreddage II that came with Peavey Revalver, and I want to route the Shreddage audio through Revalver but I don't know how to do that in Cubase.

Comment: I have never used Cubase. But from FL Studio I can say that in general for a DAW, you want to add the instrument [shreddage drums] to a track. Then add the effect to the track.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, *Shreddage II* is a VST instrument and *Peavey Revalver* is an effect.

In that case, you need to create a track that has *Shreddage II* as an instrument, and add *Peavey Revalver* as an insert effect to it.

An alternative would be to create an effect track with *Peavey Revalver* and then add this effect track to your *Shreddage II* track as a send.